# Is there any difference between +(Math.round(1.005e2) +"e-2") and Math.round(1.005e2) / 100

Tags: javascript, math, decimal, rounding

Hey guys I was just thinking about JS `Math.round()` and we all know there are some issues with numbers due to IEEE 754. But I would like to know if "/ 100" and +"e-2" make here any difference.

We know that:

```
Math.round(1.005 * 1000 ) / 1000 /* result 1.005 */
Math.round(1.005 * 100 ) / 100 /* result 1 - which is not 1.01 as we expected but this is not a surprise*/
```

But are those two equivalent or are there some hidden differences in other situation:

```
Math.round(1.005e2) / 100 /* result in 1.01 */
/* vs */
+(Math.round(1.005e2)+"e-2") /* result in 1.01 */
```

In this example they produce same result but do they always do that?

Just wonder! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

beyond just being a general bad idea to abuse coercion rules, it breaks `Infinity` / `-Infinity`:

```
> Math.round(Infinity)/100
Infinity
> +(Math.round(Infinity)+"e-2")
NaN
```

also `-0`

```
> +(Math.round(-0)+"e-2")
0
> Math.round(-0)/100
-0
```

if I saw `+"e-2"` in a code review I'd probably ~scream~ start a conversation with my manager :)

Comment: The abuse of coercion rules also defeats most JavaScript engine optimizers.